# Visual Studio 2013 build issue

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm using Workflow Foundation under Visual Studio 2013 (latest service pack). My project compiled fine for a while, but started throwing the following error.

XC1020: Build error occurred in the XAML MSBuild task: 'Object '/f537cd6c_c118_4d1c_959d_a05ed0d0c69d/na6q2vzvjwxy+8ncvo zsuonu_65.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.

I tried to delete the folder and get latest from github, then rebooted - but the error still appears. I also moved the folder to a higher root level in the file system, just in case the length of the file path caused issues with MSBuild.

Is this a dll dependency error, or could it be something else? Just in case it's a resource issue, the VM in question has 30GB of ram and 6 cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Microsoft employee gave me the solution: The problem can be solved by adding the following to app.config under configuration

```
<system.codedom>

    <compilers>

      <compiler language="c#"

      type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.5.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" extension=".cs" compilerOptions="/nostdlib /d:DEBUG;TRACE /warnaserror-" warningLevel="0"/>

      <!-- /nowarn:0162,0108,0114,0252 -->

    </compilers>

  </system.codedom>
```